Spill formula to ignore filter conditions if it's blank
I am writing a spill formula that I would like to filter a range by department and/or name, and if no selections are made spill the entire range.
Currently, I have it written where it is able to filter one or the other or both; however, I get a #Value! error if they're both blank.
=FILTER(A2:C6, IF( ISBLANK(A8),1,(A2:A6=A8) ) * IF( ISBLANK(B8),1,(B2:B6=B8) ) ,"")




Dept
Person
Value




Sales
Mark
100


Sales
Steve
100


Sales
Casey
100


MGMT
Michelle
100


MGMT
John
100



(Image to follow the formula, markdown table for testing)

One can simply add the condition when blank to the areas
=FILTER(A2:C6,((A2:A6=A8)+(A8="")>0)*((B2:B6=B8)+(B8="")>0))



Your solution is much cleaner than mine, you win :)

@MarkS. great example of a Self Answer Question.

Thank you, it started as a sincere question, and I thought more and more and had 'solved' it, and wanted something online to answer the question, but just felt there was a cleaner solution out there. I tried my best to really cleanly answer and provide everything anyone would need to do the same.

My question was more conceptual, so I may still use the LET formula, to do things to the unedited range, such as sorting or changing how it is sorted or removing duplicates, but just wanted the general concept down first.

Online has a lot of solutions regarding two filters at once and ignoring one if blank, but this problem required being able to ignore the filter entirely if all conditions are blank.
The solution I was able to determine was I could simply refer to the entire range as a formula input to spill it un-edited. Combining this with wrapping the entire formula in an IF statements gave me my desired results.
=IF( AND(M8="",N8=""),M2:O6, FILTER(M2:O6, IF( ISBLANK(M8),1,(M2:M6=M8) ) * IF( ISBLANK(N8),1,(N2:N6=N8) ),""))
Another way I was able to successfully get my desired results was by breaking this down into a Let() formula:
=LET(raw,M2:O6,filtered,FILTER(M2:O6,IF(ISBLANK(M8),1,(M2:M6=M8))*IF(ISBLANK(N8),1,(N2:N6=N8))), IF(AND(M8="",N8=""), raw,filtered))
The LET formula gives some slack on the un-edited range to allow for other actions such as UNIQUE or SORTBY, etc. so a user could modify this to change the output a few different ways
Using the first Formula:

Using the Second Formula:


Only an alternative approach using MMULT()


=FILTER(A2:C6,MMULT((A8:B8=A2:B6)+(A8:B8=""),{1;1})>1)


Or, Using LET() :
=LET(α, A8:B8, δ, A2:C6, FILTER(δ,MMULT((α=TAKE(δ,,2))+(α=""),{1;1})>1))



I think yours actually is probably the cleanest and most scalable solution.

@MarkS. Sir, yes I am late posted in the morning. Never mind.

And question regarding the {1;1} component, if i added a third condition like (A8:C8=A2:C6)+(A8:C8=""), would this remain as {1;1} because it's validating the rule not the individual conditions within it?

That one will become {1;1;1} alternatively can use SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A8:C8))^0

Awesome thank you, just curious as i haven't used mmult before

@MarkS. Sir, no issues at all.

How does this change if the conditions are vertical instead of horizontal. So our table is as is, but now the inputs to filter by are above and below each other. Does the ; become ,?

@MarkS. Sir, you need to TRANSPOSE() the conditions. =FILTER(A2:C6,MMULT(N(TOROW(A8:A9)=A2:B6),{1;1})>1) to make MMULT() work anytime you need to remember this golden rule if its applicable : MMULT function returns the matrix product of two arrays. The result from MMULT is an array that contains the same number of rows as array1 and the same number of columns as array2.
